# Electron flash plugin error 2034

Tags: adobe, electron, flash

Hello I'm building an app using electron and i want to use flash in it, the flash plugin works and load but then i get ERROR#2034 
how can i fix this ?
I'm using a software called wiziq that allows you to stream classes online 
and here is a screen-shot of the error[image]